# Javascript: Change value of x while x is object.style.left;

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

here is my situation:

I have a div with a CSS position of `"left:10px;"
All divs position's are set to fixed.
Now I put this value into a variable (JS):

```
var Left = document.getElementById("div").style.left;
```

Now I can alert it: `alert(Left);` and I get a box witch says "10px"
Here is the fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/L19rq2tk/2/

Now I want to change the value of the position by using the variable Left. I tried every possibility that came to my mind:

```
Left = "100px"; -->does not work
Left = 100px;   -->does not work
Left = "100";   -->does not work
Left = 100;     -->does not work
```

Changing the position by the following code works:

```
document.getElementById("div").style.left="100px";
```

Would be glad if anyone could help me!

Answer (score 2):

`left` works with `position:absolute`
[Here is updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L19rq2tk/1/)
**Updated**

By adding `position` weather `relative or absolute` will do the job. By adding `position:absoute` could have side effects on your design(as lonic mentioned in comment)
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L19rq2tk/5/)

Comment: No, wrong. You need to add `position:relative` or `position:absolute`. Don't just use `position:absoute` as it could have side effects on your design.

Comment: @Ionic for you information OP's does not ask about _Don't just use position:absoute as it could have side effects on your design._. so don't try to over smart

Comment: Well if you suggest the wrong thing? The OP has his answer, but it's not quite correct. If I ask how to save space on my db, I could also answer delete all row. It's correct I would have the space again, but it has the sideffect that all my data is lost. :-P In a design `position:absolute` could have worse sideeffects. Just edit your post to be correct and everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the explicit form that you mentioned at the end of your answer `document.getElementById("div").style.left="100px";`. If you are trying to avoid looking up the element each time, you should be able to do something like:

```
var savedStyle = document.getElementById("div").style;
savedStyle.left = '100px';
```

You can't set the value they way you are trying to because `Left` stores a copy of the value, it doesn't point to the same value. When you set `Left` to a new value you are only changing the value it is storing, not the value that `object.style.left` is storing. While you can have multiple variables point to the same object, you can't have multiple variables point to the same value. I've included a demo snippet showing the difference.

```js
var x = 1;
var y = x;
document.write('x = ' + x + '<br>');
document.write('y = ' + y + '<br>');
document.write('Setting y to 2<br>');
y = 2;
document.write('x is now = ' + x + '<br>');
document.write('y is now = ' + y + '<br>');

var xObj = { myValue: 3 };
var yObj = xObj;
document.write('xObj.myValue = ' + xObj.myValue + '<br>');
document.write('yObj.myValue = ' + yObj.myValue + '<br>');
document.write('Setting yObj.myValue to 1<br>');
yObj.myValue = 1;
document.write('xObj.myValue is now = ' + xObj.myValue + '<br>');
document.write('yObj.myValue is now = ' + yObj.myValue + '<br>');
```

Answer (score 1):

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L19rq2tk/4/).

You've assigned the 100px, but you haven't add `position:relative` or `position:absolute`. Due to this fact you haven't seen anything, but it was assigned in the background.

Comment: Note: By using `var Left` vs. `object.style.left` as in your fiddle, the OP hasn't assigned `"100px"` as the element's left style.

Comment: No  your right, It isn't assigned by that. It is assigned by the `object.style.left = "100px"` in the next line. It's just added to show how the assigned goes on. And it's quite shorter to use object instead of using always `document....`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

by assigning the value to the variable left nothing will be done.
you need to assign the value to the html element.

use

```
document.getElementById("div").style.left="100px";
```

left is a var which only holds the prev value.

you also need to give

```
positon:relative
```

to your div else it wont move, left, top and other position css can only be applied if the element has some position property which was missing in your.

http://jsfiddle.net/L19rq2tk/

here is your updated fiddle;